# Limits from the left and right: Does this limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

For the problem below, I came to the conclusion that the $\lim_{x\to 2}$ does not exist, as

$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}\neq \lim_{x\to 2^+}$$

Is my conclusion correct, and have I solved these problems correctly?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Congratulations.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, thats true, it's not continuos at $2$.